# On click Start Timer with No reset time on page refresh in JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

1. I am trying to create a countdown timer which will start on button click
   like 30mins will be visible on the screen, Once the user clicks on Start, it should start
2. If the user refreshes the page, It should not reset the time.
3. Stop Button to stop the counter.

I am able to create part 1, but it gets reset every time.

Here is my code:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <a href="#" id="startClock">Start Clock</a>


 <span id="count">50</span> seconds

 <script>


 function startTimer(){
 var counter = 50;
  setInterval(function() {
   counter--;
  if (counter >= 0) {
  span = document.getElementById("count");
  span.innerHTML = counter;
}
if (counter === 0) {
    alert('sorry, Lab Ended');
    clearInterval(counter);
}
  }, 1000);
 }
$("#startClock").click(function(){
startTimer();
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: Any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=Timer+resets+on+page+refresh+site:stackoverflow.com) don't work for you?

Comment: I tried all the link, either they don't have button click start, or time is not visible on page load

Comment: Not all but more than 20 i tried

Comment: Then we can't help, the answers to this general question will be the same as what you've already read. Please show your attempt to really store the timer value (to `localStorage` or cookie or database or whatever you've tried), we probably can fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to save you counter state using `window.localStorage.setItem(key, value)` and get later the counter state with `window.localStorage.getItem(key)`. And you remove the counter from localStorage with `window.localStorage.removeItem(key)` if the counter is done.

Try the code below with pause and restart features:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <a href="#" id="restartClock">Restart Clock</a>
 <a href="#" id="startClock">Start Clock</a>
 <a href="#" id="pauseClock">Pause Clock</a>


 <span id="count">50</span> seconds

 <script>
   var initialValue = 50;
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");
     var canCount = true;
     var id;
     if (counter) {
       $("span#count").html(counter);
     } else {
       localStorage.setItem("counter", initialValue);
       counter = initialValue;
       $("span#count").html(initialValue);
     }

     function startTimer() {
       if (localStorage.getItem("counter") && id === undefined) {
         id = setInterval(function() {
           if (canCount) {
             localStorage.setItem("counter", --counter);
             span = document.getElementById("count");
             span.innerHTML = counter;
             if (counter <= 0) {
               localStorage.removeItem("counter")
               clearInterval(id);
               id = undefined;
             }
           }
         }, 1000);
       }
     }

     $("#startClock").click(startTimer);

     $("#restartClock").click(function(){
        counter = initialValue;
        localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
        $("span#count").html(counter);
     });

     $("#pauseClock").click(function() {
       $(this).html(canCount?"Continue Clock":"Pause Clock");
       canCount = !canCount;
     });
   });

 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is calculate the timestamp of 30 minutes ahead and save it to local storage. When the page load you should first look into the local starage to check if there is a running timer, if there is then show it starting the interval with countdown, if it doesn't you calculate the timestamp, save it to local storage and start the countdown

Comment: I tried local storage but didn't work, Can you please help

Comment: What did you save into local storage? I would save `const finalTime = new Date().getTime + 1000 * 60 * 30` Then you can know how much is left to the end. If you post your local storage try I would be able to correct it

Answer (score -1):

```
 function startTimer(){
  var counter = 1800000;
   setInterval(function() {
     counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
     localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
     span = document.getElementById("count");
     span.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("counter");
     counter = $('#count').text();
     }
     if (counter == 0) {
       alert('sorry, Lab Ended');
       clearInterval(counter);
       localStorage.clear('counter');
     }
    }, 1000);
   }
   $("#startClock").click(function(){
     startTimer();
    });
```

you can try local storage to do this, hope the above code will help you.